# Upload de Arquivo no Servidor Tomcat

Tags: servidor, tomcat, file-upload

Tenho um sistema pronto para subir para o servidor tomcat, só que esse sistema utiliza upload de aquivos com catalina base, e quando subo o sistema para o servidor tomcat o upload de arquivo não funciona, alguém sabe se é preciso cria as pastas onde os arquivos ficam salvos no servidor tomcat e como faço isso?

Comment: Primeiro verifique se o diretório que está fazendo o upload da imagem realmente existe. Depois o usuário que subiu a aplicação (tomcat) tem permissão de escrita nesse diretório. Tem log de execução?

Comment: valeu Diego, mais já consegui, faltava um acesso via ftp do tomcat, com ele eu criei a pasta no servidor e a aplicação funcionou.